# VBA Access - how to set an object with the currently open database

Tags: vba, ms-access

Guys how do I set an object to a currently open database - the code below looks for the database, if it cannot find it it opens it however, if it is open then the code fall over at the acObj application.run call as acObj is not set to the database....

```
Set acObj = CreateObject("Access.Application")

If Len(Dir("C:\Users\" & ComputerName() & "\Documents\Components*.laccdb")) = 0 Then 'if the datebase is not running then open it
    acObj.Application.Visible = True
    acObj.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\" & ComputerName() & "\Documents\Components\Working_Blank.accdb"
    acObj.Application.UserControl = True
End If

acObj.Application.Run "Build_And_Call_LogProfile", _Name, _date
```

Comment: What version of Access are you using?

Comment: How do you handle running "Build_And_Call_LogProfile" if the database is opened normally?  While this isn't the answer to your direct question, could what you are attempting to do be handled by just using an Autoexec macro so that just runs on load when that database is opened?

Comment: no not going to work - as I need to pass variables

Comment: basically I need to tell acObj to set itself to the open database

Comment: I don't have a specific answer, though it looks like your solution will involve using workspaces.  Best link I could find to do what you want would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448338/attempt-to-connect-to-a-valid-database-from-outside-access-outlook-excel-using

Comment: thanks but I dont think so as even in this code the database is opened by the sub - I want my sub to run with an already open database

Comment: Okay, sorry I can't really be of any more help figuring out how to set the db to another open database.  Though if you are up for alternative methods to do what you are looking for I would be happy to throw some ideas at you.

Comment: @Newd - thanks man help appreciated - I have cracked this with this  line

Comment: so full code If Len(Dir("C:\Users\" & ComputerName() & "\Documents\Muncher_Components\*.laccdb")) = 0 Then
'if the datebase is not running then open it

    Set acObj = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    acObj.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\" & ComputerName() & "\Documents\Muncher_Components\CruncherVersion_Working_Blank.accdb"
    acObj.Application.UserControl = True
    
   Else
   'if the datbase is then get the currenlty active database
   Set acObj = GetObject(, "Access.Application")

End If


acObj.Application.Run "Build_And_Call_LogProfile"

Answer (score 1):

```
If Len(Dir("C:\Users\" & ComputerName() & "\Documents\Muncher_Components\*.laccdb")) = 0 Then
    'if the datebase is not running then open it

    Set acObj = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    acObj.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\" & ComputerName() & "\Documents\Muncher_Components\CruncherVersion_Working_Blank.accdb"
    acObj.Application.UserControl = True

    Else
    'if the datbase is then get the currenlty active database
    Set acObj = GetObject(, "Access.Application")

End If


acObj.Application.Run "Build_And_Call_LogProfile"
```

Comment: If the database was closed abnormally the laccdb file may still be there but the database not be open. Have you had this issue and if so did you find another way?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can just use **GetObject()** in both open or closed scenarios:

```
Set acObj = GetObject("C:\Users\" & ComputerName() & "\Documents\Muncher_Components\CruncherVersion_Working_Blank.accdb")
acObj.Application.UserControl = True
acObj.Application.Run "Build_And_Call_LogProfile"
```