# convert mdb to accdb into excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

In my project, I'm updating access database table datas with excel vba. I used to use .mdb file. To do this I wrote this codes

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = OpenDatabase("\\ptrisf02\group\Corrolog\CorroLogDB\Test1.accdb", False, False, ";pwd=12345tec")

vbSO = Me.TextBox1.Value

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblSO WHERE strSO = '" & vbSO & "'", dbOpenDynaset)  'tblSO_archive

rs.Edit
'Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, 1).End(xlDown)).Select

rs!strSNFB = Sheets("v25").Cells(2, 2)     'FAN MODULE
rs!strTSNFB = Sheets("v25").Cells(2, 3)
rs!strCSNFB = Sheets("v25").Cells(2, 4)
rs!strMINFB = Sheets("v25").Cells(2, 5)
rs!strFULLFB = Sheets("v25").Cells(2, 6)

rs!strSN12B = Sheets("v25").Cells(4, 2)     'LPC
rs!strTSN12B = Sheets("v25").Cells(4, 3)
rs!strCSN12B = Sheets("v25").Cells(4, 4)
rs!strMIN12B = Sheets("v25").Cells(4, 5)
rs!strFULL12B = Sheets("v25").Cells(4, 6)

rs!strSNFF = Sheets("v25").Cells(5, 2)      'FAN FRAME
rs!strTSNFF = Sheets("v25").Cells(5, 3)
rs!strCSNFF = Sheets("v25").Cells(5, 4)
rs!strMINFF = Sheets("v25").Cells(5, 5)
rs!strFULLFF = Sheets("v25").Cells(5, 6)

rs!strSNIGB3 = Sheets("v25").Cells(6, 2)    'IGB
rs!strTSNIGB3 = Sheets("v25").Cells(6, 3)
rs!strCSNIGB3 = Sheets("v25").Cells(6, 4)
rs!strMINIGB3 = Sheets("v25").Cells(6, 5)
rs!strPERFIGB3 = Sheets("v25").Cells(6, 6)
rs!strFULLIGB3 = Sheets("v25").Cells(6, 7)

rs!strSNHPCR = Sheets("v25").Cells(9, 2)    'HPC rot
rs!strTSNHPCR = Sheets("v25").Cells(9, 3)
rs!strCSNHPCR = Sheets("v25").Cells(9, 4)
rs!strMINHPCR = Sheets("v25").Cells(9, 5)
rs!strFULLHPCR = Sheets("v25").Cells(9, 6)

rs!strSNHPCFS = Sheets("v25").Cells(8, 2)   'HPC stat
rs!strTSNHPCFS = Sheets("v25").Cells(8, 3)
rs!strCSNHPCFS = Sheets("v25").Cells(8, 4)
rs!strMINHPCFS = Sheets("v25").Cells(8, 5)
rs!strFULLHPCFS = Sheets("v25").Cells(8, 6)

rs!strSNHPCRS = Sheets("v25").Cells(10, 2)  'DIFF CASE
rs!strTSNHPCRS = Sheets("v25").Cells(10, 3)
rs!strCSNHPCRS = Sheets("v25").Cells(10, 4)
rs!strMINHPCRS = Sheets("v25").Cells(10, 5)
rs!strFULLHPCRS = Sheets("v25").Cells(10, 6)

rs!strSNCCS = Sheets("v25").Cells(11, 2)    'COMB ASSY
rs!strTSNCCS = Sheets("v25").Cells(11, 3)
rs!strCSNCCS = Sheets("v25").Cells(11, 4)
rs!strMINCCS = Sheets("v25").Cells(11, 5)
rs!strFULLCCS = Sheets("v25").Cells(11, 6)


rs!strSNCCH = Sheets("v25").Cells(12, 2)    '#4BRG COMP.
rs!strTSNCCH = Sheets("v25").Cells(12, 3)
rs!strCSNCCH = Sheets("v25").Cells(12, 4)
rs!strMINCCH = Sheets("v25").Cells(12, 5)
rs!strFULLCCH = Sheets("v25").Cells(12, 6)

rs!strSNHPTN = Sheets("v25").Cells(13, 2)   'HPT STG1 Nozz.
rs!strTSNHPTN = Sheets("v25").Cells(13, 3)
rs!strCSNHPTN = Sheets("v25").Cells(13, 4)
rs!strMINHPTN = Sheets("v25").Cells(13, 5)
rs!strFULLHPTN = Sheets("v25").Cells(13, 6)


rs!strSNHPTR = Sheets("v25").Cells(14, 2)   'HPT
rs!strTSNHPTR = Sheets("v25").Cells(14, 3)
rs!strCSNHPTR = Sheets("v25").Cells(14, 4)
rs!strMINHPTR = Sheets("v25").Cells(14, 5)
rs!strFULLHPTR = Sheets("v25").Cells(14, 6)



rs!strSNLPTRS = Sheets("v25").Cells(16, 2)      'LPT MODULE
rs!strTSNLPTRS = Sheets("v25").Cells(16, 3)
rs!strCSNLPTRS = Sheets("v25").Cells(16, 4)
rs!strMINLPTRS = Sheets("v25").Cells(16, 5)
rs!strFULLLPTRS = Sheets("v25").Cells(16, 6)

rs!strSNTRF = Sheets("v25").Cells(17, 2)    'TEC
rs!strTSNTRF = Sheets("v25").Cells(17, 3)
rs!strCSNTRF = Sheets("v25").Cells(17, 4)
rs!strMINTRF = Sheets("v25").Cells(17, 5)
rs!strFULLTRF = Sheets("v25").Cells(17, 6)

rs!strSNAGB = Sheets("v25").Cells(18, 2)    'EGB
rs!strTSNAGB = Sheets("v25").Cells(18, 3)
rs!strCSNAGB = Sheets("v25").Cells(18, 4)
rs!strMINAGB = Sheets("v25").Cells(18, 5)
rs!strFULLAGB = Sheets("v25").Cells(18, 6)

rs.Update

rs.Close
db.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

It was working correctly but I decided to changed .mdb to .accdb. After I changed it it's not updating database. I don't understand why it's not updating. If there are an suggestions please response.

[references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vseTN.png)

Comment: What is your Dao version? Vba-ide -> Extras -> References, See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448338/attempt-to-connect-to-a-valid-database-from-outside-access-outlook-excel-using

Comment: @ComputerVersteher My DAO version is **Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library**

Comment: Now read my link! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448338/attempt-to-connect-to-a-valid-database-from-outside-access-outlook-excel-using

Comment: @ComputerVersteher I tried to add **Microsoft Office 15.0 Access Database Engine Object Library** but it gives me this error **Name conflicts with existing module,project or object library**. I will add my reference's photo.

Comment: Read all! Most voted answer says: "So get rid of the 3.6 reference and use a more recent library. "!

Comment: @ComputerVersteher It's solved thanks for your help.